# IIS config: single instance for multiple site

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis

I have an asp.net MVC website with multiple domains, I wonder if it is possible to config IIS in a way that all the subdomains will point to the same instance instead of having a separate instance for each subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out myself. All I need to do is to right click on the site -> edit binding and add the subdomain as the host name